# 'TimeOfDay' is not supported in LINQ to Entities - Find total seconds in Linq 2 SQL

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, datetime, timespan

When I do the following :

```
[EdmFunction("Edm", "TruncateTime")]
public static DateTime? TruncateDateTime(DateTime? inputDate)
{
    return inputDate.HasValue ? inputDate.Value.Date : (DateTime?)null;
}

 [EdmFunction("Edm", "TotalSeconds")]
public static double? GetTotalSeconds(DateTime? inputDate)
{
    return inputDate.HasValue ? inputDate.Value.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds: (double?)null;
}

var employeeSelection = (from c in MyContext.Employees.Where(c => c.From.HasValue && c.To.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds != 0)
...
select new Employee

{


 To = c.To != DateTime.MinValue && c.To.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds != 0 ? TruncateDateTime(c.To).Value :
              c.To != DateTime.MinValue && c.To.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds == 0 ? c.From.Value.AddMinutes(30) :  DateTime.MinValue

}
```

I get this :

> Additional information: The specified type member 'TimeOfDay' is not
>   supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and
>   entity navigation properties are supported.

And when I try this :

```
var employeeSelection = (from c in MyContext.Employees.Where(c => c.From.HasValue && GetTotalSeconds(c.To) != 0)
...
select new Employee

{


 To = c.To != DateTime.MinValue && GetTotalSeconds(c.To) != 0 ? TruncateDateTime(c.To).Value :
              c.To != DateTime.MinValue && GetTotalSeconds(c.To) == 0 ? c.From.Value.AddMinutes(30) :  DateTime.MinValue

}
```

I get :

> Additional information: The specified method
>   'System.Nullable`1[System.Double]
>   GetTotalSeconds(System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime])' on the type
>   'GetDateRangeMethod' cannot be translated into a LINQ to Entities
>   store expression.

How can I find the total seconds in Linq to SQL ?

Thanks

Comment: try to use DbFunctions https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions(v=vs.113).aspx

Answer (score 4):

Try using [SqlFunctions.DatePart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466176%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

e.g. instead of

```
var employeeSelection = (from c in MyContext.Employees
          .Where(c => c.From.HasValue && GetTotalSeconds(c.To) != 0)
```

try something like

```
var employeeSelection = (from c in MyContext.Employees
          .Where(c => c.From.HasValue && SqlFunctions.DatePart("second", c.To) != 0)
```

For NetMage

```
var employeeSelection = (from c in MyContext.Employees
          .Where(c => c.From.HasValue && (SqlFunctions.DatePart("second", c.To) + (60 * SqlFunctions.DatePart("minute", c.To)) + (3600 * SqlFunctions.DatePart("hour", c.To))) != 0)
```

Where

> TotalSeconds = (SqlFunctions.DatePart("second", c.To) + (60 * SqlFunctions.DatePart("minute", c.To)) + (3600 * SqlFunctions.DatePart("hour", c.To)))

Comment: The two functions aren't the same thing.

Comment: @NetMage Indeed they aren't, this is what a 'helpfull' answer because I show a way to get the seconds, and then expand upon this answer to give: TotalSeconds = SqlFunctions.DatePart("second", c.To) + (60 * SqlFunctions.DatePart("minute", c.To)) + (3600 * SqlFunctions.DatePart("hour", c.To))

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Date and Time Canonical Functions for LINQ-to-Entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738563(VS.100).aspx) and if you are unsure on how to call them, have a look at [How to: Call Canonical Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456873.aspx)

The methods that are available should be able to solve the problem your currently having where the operations your currently using are not supported by the database.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a Linq-To-Entities Query you can only perform operations which can be executed by your used database management system.

You will need to get your desired information from your DB and create a list from that query, than that will be called Linq-To-Objects and you will be able to perform you desired operation.

Comment: When speaking on hundreds and thousands of records this solution will take a LONG time .

Comment: it depends on how many columns you are selecting. You need to filter your desired data and not select everything where 80% maybe is not needed.